# 2012 Mazda 5: P0422 Code

Tags: emissions, mazda-5

My 2012 Mazda 5 Grand Touring has been having the following problem.  Sometimes it takes an extended amount of time to start and other times it will crank normally, but then sputter and stall.  When it stalls, the second crank always works and once the car is running there are no obvious problems.  These problems eventually led to a check engine light and a P0422 code.  I was led to the evaporative emissions system and I have so far replaced the gas cap and the canister purge valve.  The problem still persists.  Does anyone have a suggestion for which part they would try next?  When I read about what happens when you have a faulty canister purge valve, the description matched my problem perfectly.  I'm beginning to wonder if I have a bad sensor somewhere.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Mechanics.SE :) Which engine do you have on your Mazda?

Comment: It is the 2.5 liter